# Install Windows 10 in VM without ACPI (battery etc.)?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, battery

On linux, I use virtualbox to attempt to install Windows 10 inside a VM. I have experienced shutdown and suspend to ram issues whenever a Windows VM was running, which is why I would like to have my Windows VM not be aware of all the power management stuff (i.e. the battery etc).

I hence disable acpi in virtualbox:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm {uuid of vm} --acpi off
```

My problem is causes the Windows 10 install medium (the iso), which normaly works fine, to fail (with BSOD) with the a mixture of those codes:

`0x0000225`,`0x0000017`

How would one install Windows 10 VM that does not have ACPI functionality.

Of course I know about the inferiority of Windows with regards to Linux, but having made Ubuntu work without ACPI and APIC I really think Windows10 should be able to pull of the same. Inside the VM there is no need to have a battery etc.

Having read some articles on the internet I expect that I need to disable ACPI in windows and this to happen in the device manager.

[image]

Comment: The Windows VM is isolated and will in any case not be aware of the power details of the host. The default BIOS of VirtualBox might be having problems with ACPI off.

Comment: @harrymc My observation has been that it actually is aware of the battery level. I can see it loading. Also the BIOS of Virtualbox with ACPI off is fine for linux.

Comment: That does not mean that it is fine for Windows.

Comment: @harrymc For me it remains unclear how much a vm guest (i.e. windows) here is able to mess with ACPI stuff. The fact that it shows me the correct battery percentage makes a point that to some extend windows is meddling here. I need the VM guest to not be even able to do that. I can do that with linux, as when disabling apci in virtualbox is set it still works. Only windows stops working without ACPI, which again to be clear I need it to, unless I this ACPI interference might have negative consequence (i.e. prevent power states on host). At no point would I mind if or if not Windows is "fine".

Comment: @harrymc To be clear. I need the Window machine for some work related stuff. At my own free choice, I would not want to touch anything Microsoft with a 10 feet pole. The fact that even from inside the VM lots of stuff happens (i.e. the VM gues - windows - seems able to spit out even cpu microcode updates and interact with UEFI) is not making me a happier user. The question is hence how to make the windows guest vm  not instant crash upon removal of ACPI

Answer (score 0):

To be absolutely clear, VM guest should have no effect on your host hardware behavior other than what is necessary for it to run. If that would not be the case, bugreport it to Oracle.

Thus, any ACPI issues of your host won't be effected by the guest. They MAY affect the guest, but I doubt that. Guest's ACPI bus is emulated, not virtualized. And without ACPI you lose more than just battery level indicator.

Short answer to your question is: don't ask questions you think you know answers for. ("It is fine, tell me am I right!")

Ask questions you need answers for.

Do you need ACPI interface for Win10? Yes. It just won't install if it do not see the management interface.

Do you need ACPI for anything than battery levels? Yes. For all windows started from '95 it is preferred to have ACPI interface for proper CPU control.

Also, you won't be able to shutdown (`VBoxManage controlvm … acpipowerbutton`) the guest from host console without it.

Can your ACPI issues on host be fixed? Likely, yes. Upgrade your BIOS.